# Multiple Tables auto-assigning round-table SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010

I'm trying to build a complex SQL that would auto-assign assignments to workers in a round-table fashion. So for example, I have 50 workers and 500 assignments. I want each worker to get evenly 10 assignments, however they might not all get 10, some may get more because there are "IF" variables that may have 1 worker get 15 and 1 get 5. Here are the variables that make this SQL complex. I have 2 tables that this data is going to be pulling from and updating. "tblUser" is where all of the worker's information is held, fields [programs] and [language] are the variables that we have to consider when we assign. Workers may only know 1 program, 2 programs, or 3 programs. It specifically says which program each employee knows.

For example, worker 1 knows MC/CF and that is placed in field [programs]. Now for [language] each worker may or may not know more than 1 language. If they do, it is listed in the [language] field. We assume all workers know english so lets take that into consideration. However english only workers should not get spanish assignments.

Now for the 2nd table, "CFRRR" this table is where the assignments are located. [assignedto] is the field that the worker who get's assigned the case has that worker's [WorkerID] placed in. [workername] is the field that the worker who get's assigned the case has that worker's [username] placed in. [language] is a field that has what language the assignment is in and [program] has what program the assignment is in. The complicated variable here is that [program] in CFRRR may only say MC, but a worker with MC/CF can can the assignment because they have MC as one of their programs, so a match sql wouldn't work for that.

I have a round-table SQL now, but it doesn't take into consideration any of the variables (language, program) which is really important in assigning.

```
Public Function GetNextAssignee() As Long

    Dim db As dao.Database
    Dim rs As dao.Recordset
    Dim strSQL As String

    Set db = CurrentDb
    strSQL = "SELECT TOP 1 WorkerID FROM tblUser ORDER BY TS ASC"
    Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(strSQL, dbOpenDynaset)
    If Not rs.BOF And Not rs.EOF Then
        strSQL = "UPDATE tblUser SET TS = " & DMax("[TS]", "tblUser") + 1 & " WHERE [WorkerID]= " & rs!workerid
        db.Execute strSQL, dbFailOnError
        GetNextAssignee = rs!workerid
    Else
        GetNextAssignee = 0
    End If

    rs.Close
    db.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
    Set db = Nothing

End Function
Public Function AssignNullProjects() As Long

    Dim db As dao.Database
    Dim rs As dao.Recordset
    Dim strSQL As String

    Set db = CurrentDb
    strSQL = "SELECT CFRRRID FROM CFRRR WHERE assignedto Is Null"
    Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(strSQL, dbOpenDynaset)
    If Not rs.BOF And Not rs.EOF Then
        While Not rs.EOF
            strSQL = "UPDATE CFRRR SET assignedto = " & GetNextAssignee & " WHERE CFRRRID = " & rs!CFRRRID
            db.Execute strSQL, dbFailOnError
            rs.MoveNext
        Wend
    End If

    rs.Close
    db.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
    Set db = Nothing
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks almost done. Now you need to enhance your `GetNextAssignee()` function to accept two parameters: program and language: `GetNextAssignee(program As String, language As String)`

In the function you need to modify the select statement to retrieve the employees based on the passed in program and language:

```
strSQL = "SELECT TOP 1 WorkerID FROM tblUser WHERE [program] LIKE '*" & program & "*' AND [language] = '" & language & "' ORDER BY TS ASC"
```

Please note that in the statement above I have used parameters embedded into SQL. You should not do this in the production code. You should always use [parameterised](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff820966.aspx) queries

In your `AssignNullProjects()` you need to modify the select statement to retrieve the program and the language from the jobs:

```
strSQL = "SELECT CFRRRID, [program], [language] FROM CFRRR WHERE assignedto Is Null"
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(strSQL, dbOpenDynaset)
If Not rs.BOF And Not rs.EOF Then
    While Not rs.EOF
        strSQL = "UPDATE CFRRR SET assignedto = " & GetNextAssignee(rs!program, rs!language) & " WHERE CFRRRID = " & rs!CFRRRID
        db.Execute strSQL, dbFailOnError
        rs.MoveNext
    Wend
End If
```

Surely, your logic can be further enhanced, i.e. you may also need to check the job manhours, workers roster, holidays, etc.

Comment: You're absolutely right! I completely forgot about the manhours and I actually have an attendance table that tracks everything! How would I get that variable included into my coding? My table is attendance, the employee's ID is in field [userID] and when they log in the day is entered in field [AttendanceDay] and the time is [AttendanceTime] and the [Status] states if the employee is "Available" or "Leave" so basically the code should be able to filter and only assigned to workers who are logged in "available" status.

Comment: Just continue to enhance the functions one step at a time. I am pretty sure more requirements will come up during the UAT. It is part of the development process.